# Computing the outstanding balance of a loan in r by referencing the balance in a previous row

Tags: r

I have a data set which contains multiple customers each having multiple loans. The loans have monthly repayments. See example of the data frame called data1 (see a sample for data1 below).

The formula for Closing Balance for Fore_Cast_Horizon = 1 is:
Account_Balance + (Account_Balance*Interest_Rate) - Instalment

The formula for Closing Balance where Fore_Cast_Horizon > 1 is
Account_Balance[i-1] + (Account_Balance[i-1]*Interest_Rate[i] - Instalment[i]

This need to reset for each new ACCOUNT_ID in the data.

I need help in programming this in r

```
Customer_ID ACCOUNT_ID Account_Balance Instalment Interest_Rate Fore_Cast_Horizon Closing Balance
100         2          500             50         0.02          1                 460.0000       
100         2          500             50         0.02          2                 419.2000
010         2          500             50         0.02          3                 377.5840
100         4          800             80         0.03          1                 744.0000
100         4          800             80         0.03          2                 686.3200
100         4          800             80         0.03          3                 626.9096
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following solves your problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
        Customer_ID = c(100L, 100L, 10L, 100L, 100L, 100L),
         ACCOUNT_ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
    Account_Balance = c(500L, 500L, 500L, 800L, 800L, 800L),
         Instalment = c(50L, 50L, 50L, 80L, 80L, 80L),
      Interest_Rate = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03),
  Fore_Cast_Horizon = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
    Closing.Balance = c(460, 419.2, 377.584, 744, 686.32, 626.9096)
      )

df %>% 
  group_by(ACCOUNT_ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    idg = row_number(ACCOUNT_ID), 
    raux = ifelse(idg == 1, 0, Interest_Rate),
    CB2 = Account_Balance * cumprod(1+Interest_Rate) - 
      cumsum(Instalment * cumprod(1+raux)), raux = NULL, idg = NULL) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  as.data.frame()

#>   Customer_ID ACCOUNT_ID Account_Balance Instalment Interest_Rate
#> 1         100          2             500         50          0.02
#> 2         100          2             500         50          0.02
#> 3          10          2             500         50          0.02
#> 4         100          4             800         80          0.03
#> 5         100          4             800         80          0.03
#> 6         100          4             800         80          0.03
#>   Fore_Cast_Horizon Closing.Balance      CB2
#> 1                 1        460.0000 460.0000
#> 2                 2        419.2000 419.2000
#> 3                 3        377.5840 377.5840
#> 4                 1        744.0000 744.0000
#> 5                 2        686.3200 686.3200
#> 6                 3        626.9096 626.9096
```